# Efficient data structure for representing a graph

Tags: c, data-structures, graph

I have to implement a directed graph (digraph) which is permitted to have multiple arcs (multigraph), like in the image linked. The graph has to be optimized to handle a lot of nodes but a few edges between two of them. The graph has to be frequently updated and it has to support efficient path search. Which is an efficient data structure to have a compromise between space used and time for a query? The language is standard C (only libc).

[graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HyfZ.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "frequently updated"? That edges change or that nodes change e.g. nodes are added or deleted?

Comment: What is a "path search"?

Comment: It meas that nodes can be added and edges as well. Edges can be deleted or added

Comment: Path search in the sense that I have to search for nodes that are liked to a particular node of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have `NODE_COUNT` nodes.  You create a vector `GRAPH` of length `NODE_COUNT`.  On the entry `X` you have an array of variable size (dynamically allocated).  Each entry looks like `GRAPH[X]=[A1, A2, A3]` to represent the edges `{ (X,A1), (X,A2), (X,A3) }`.

If you need to search for some edges it is also convenient to use a binary search tree on the entry `GRAPH[X]`.  If you have more than 6 edges for each node you can consider this possibility as well instead of using a non-ordered array on position `GRAPH[X]`.

Because the graph has many nodes and few edges you should not use a matrix.

If you have millions or billions of nodes the problem is different and you should think at using [BDDs](https://www7.in.tum.de/um/courses/logic/SS11/folien/bdd-english-4.pdf).  This is another topic, I do not enter in details in this thread.  The idea is that a graph can be represented as the characteristic function of a set representing the graph.

Comment: Your answer should mention the name of this data structure: it’s an adjacency list. And it’s indeed a good representation for a sparse graph that’s frequently updated, as required by OP.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, `GRAPH[X]` can be an adjacency list or it can be a binary search tree if he needs to do faster lookups or he can use an ordered array for logarithmic-time search of an edge -- he can choose one of these depending on the average number of edges of each node and depending on the type of operations he needs to execute on the graph.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  ... Or, he can choose anything to represent a set -- for example, Godel numbers or chinese remainder theorem can represent sets (although they are practical only if the indices of nodes are not big), https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113142/using-g%C3%B6del-numbering-to-represent-sets-of-real-numbers

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Adjacency Matrix. It's essentially a 2D array that shows the adjacency list. 
[image: adjaceny matrix]

Here's an example. I believe they are fairly quick, it takes Θ(1) time to determine if an edge exists in the graph.

This would be good if "frequent updating" referred to updating the edges because it takes constant time to update one of the values. (ie. adding edge(3, 2) would take constant time because you would just increment the value at 3,2 in the matrix)

For determining shortest path Dijkstra’s algorithm would be your best bet.

Comment: Does this support the "frequent updating", including expansion and shrinking?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie depends on what OP means with "frequent updating". If he means frequent adding and deletion of nodes then no. If he means frequent adding deletion of edges then yes

Comment: @PaulOgilvie by "frequent updating" do you mean adding/removing edges or adding/removing vertices ?

Comment: Note that this could raise the question *"How do I implement an Adjacency Matrix in C?"*. If you suggest a 2d array, than with "a lot of nodes but a few edges" it's a pretty sparse one and an "efficient path search" could be tricky.

Comment: An adjacency matrix fails the "multiple arcs" requirement

Comment: @hager if you have 2 instances of edge(3,1) you would have a 2 at position 3,1 in the matrix, does this not represent multiple arcs ?

Comment: @Gpsy That would work assuming the edges are unweighted, but the example graph had weights attached to all edges.

Comment: @hager if those are actually weights than you are correct, I interpreted those numbers as labels for each of the weights since they go 1-5 as if they were numbering the edges

Comment: @Gpsy Now I see - you're probably right in assuming those are labels, I never took the time to actually read the numbers, which on a closer look appear to be labels.